# Why does M-x underline-region doesn't work?

Tags: formatting

I don't know if I'm using the command correctly or not.
I select the region to be underlined and then pass the command `M-x underline-region` and it doesn't work.
For example

if the text is `SAMPLE` which I select and pass the command within Emacs, the output looks like this

```
 _^HS_^HA_^HM_^HP_^HL_^HE
```

How should I be using this command? I found this command by co-incidence.
When I searched on this topic, I found [ul.el](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-release/blob/master/lisp/textmodes/underline.el). I'm not good at elisp yet, so couldn't make any sense of the code.
The comment in the code says:

```
"Underline all nonblank characters in the region.
Works by overstriking underscores.
Called from program, takes two arguments START and END
which specify the range to operate on."
```

Which means that the output should look this SAMPLE (*with an underline below it - I'm unable to get it in Markdown*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to work as advertised. Note that what looks like `^H` in the emacs buffer is really a backspace character. If you were to print `_^HS` on an old fashioned dot matrix printer, it would print the underscore, then the print head would go back one step, and it would print the S. Result: an underlined S! And so on for the next characters.

Basically, this shows the age of emacs. Emacs is *old*, from before dot matrix printers even (I think), and this was a common technique back then. Even now, you will find that programs like [less](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/) will emulate this behaviour! So if you take a file in which you have run `M-x underline-region` on some text, then save it, and view it with less in a terminal, you will see underlined text.

What this will *not* do, however, is to display the text as underlined in the emacs buffer. Though it is conceivable that some modes exist (or could be written) that will display it that way.

Comment: I mention dot matrix printers, but there were earlier printers that would print characters one by one, and the backspace technique works on those too.

Comment: Are u referring to this comment?  
;;; Commentary:


;; This package deals with the primitive form of underlining

;; consisting of prefixing each character with "_\^h". The entry

;; point `underline-region' performs such underlining on a region.

;; The entry point `ununderline-region' removes it.

Comment: I admit I had only read the doc string and not looked into the source code. So no, I did not refer to that comment, but it is saying the same thing.